Asserts for tests
I need to add asserts to my tests. However, when I try to do this, it returns org to me.
junit.ComparisonFailure:   
Expected :This is a new note!  
Actual   :

I have to compare the data with an already created record, is everything ok there and was it conducted correctly
package java_3lab;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class lab3 extends TestBase {
    @Test
    public void a_testLogin() {
        app.getNavigationHelper().openHomePage();
        AccountData user = new AccountData(app.getLoginHelper());
        user.login();
    }

    @Test
    public void b_testAddNote() {
        app.getNavigationHelper().openHomePage();
        AccountData user = new AccountData(app.getLoginHelper());
        NoteData note = new NoteData(app.getNoteHelper());
        note.create("Это новая заметка!");

        // Получаем текст последней созданной заметки
        String lastCreatedNoteText = app.getNoteHelper().getLastCreatedNoteText();

        // Проверяем, что текст заметки соответствует ожидаемому
        Assert.assertEquals("Это новая заметка!", lastCreatedNoteText);
    }

    @Test
    public void c_testEditNote() {
        app.getNavigationHelper().openHomePage();
        AccountData user = new AccountData(app.getLoginHelper());
        NoteEdit note = new NoteEdit(app.getNoteEditHelper());
        note.edit("Теперь это исправленная заметка!");
    }
}

package java_3lab;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class NoteData {
    private NoteHelper noteHelper;

    public NoteData(NoteHelper noteHelper) {
        this.noteHelper = noteHelper;
    }

    public void create(String noteText) {
        noteHelper.create(noteText);
    }

    public String getLastCreatedNoteText() {
        return noteHelper.getLastCreatedNoteText();
    }
}

package java_3lab;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class NoteHelper extends HelperBase {

    public NoteHelper(ApplicationManager app) {
        super(app);
    }

    public String getLastCreatedNoteText() {
        WebElement postWebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='page_wall_posts']/div[1]"));
        String postContent = postWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='wall_text']/div/div")).getText();
        return postContent;
    }

    public void create(String noteText) {
        NavigationHelper navigationHelper = app.getNavigationHelper();
        navigationHelper.openHomePage();

        driver.findElement(By.id("DiText")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("DiText")).sendKeys(noteText);
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_save")).click();
    }
}

I've tried to do this in various ways, including:
public String getLastCreatedNoteText(){
    return driver.findElement(By.id("DiText")).getText();
}


Have you tried adding a WebDriverWait for visible before pulling the text? Have you put a breakpoint on that line and stepping through the code to see if it works? My guess is that it's a timing issue and a wait will work.

Great. I added it as an answer. Please accept it so that the question doesn't get left unanswered.

I would suggest adding a wait before pulling the text, e.g.
public String getLastCreatedNoteText(){
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("DiText"))).getText();
}

